# Insert into Two table having the same database but shaing the same id

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a php code that will insert value to to tables but i want table one "id" and table two "product_id" to be the same thing. this is my below code that insert values to the database but table one "id" do not correspond to table two "product_id"

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

$name = $_POST['name'];
$image = $_POST['image'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$stock = $_POST['stock'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$status = $_POST['status'];

require_once('dbConnect.php');

$sql ="SELECT id FROM product ORDER BY id ASC";

$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$id = 0;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
    $id = $row['id'];
}

$imagename = "$id.png";

$path = "uploads/$id.png";
$storage = "$id.png";

$actualpath = "http://localhost/markeet/$path";


$sql = "INSERT INTO product (name,image,price,stock,draft,description,status,created_at,last_update) VALUES ('$name','$storage','$price','$stock','0','$description','$status','','');";

$sql .= "INSERT INTO product_category (product_id, category_id)
VALUES ('', '$stock');";

if ($con->multi_query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New records created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
    file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($image));
    echo "Successfully Uploaded";
}

mysqli_close($con);
}else{
    echo "Error";
}
```

Comment: you will need to make 2 queries and get the (autoincremented)id from the first to use for the 2nd

Comment: how will i make table one  "product" colum  "id" to have the same value with table two "product_category' column "product_id" to have same value ?

Comment: Your `while` loop is just overwriting the `$id` variable each time, so the end result is that you just get the id of the last row. Why don't you just use `SELECT max(id) FROM product` instead of looping through all the IDs?

Comment: please edit the code to the correct form. am coding and android app to send data to the sql but must insert into two tables so that it will show on the android app once it is called for

Answer (score 1):

In your code you use `multi_query()` to run your both queries right after each other.

I suggest the following:

```
// Insert product
    $queryInsertProduct = "INSERT INTO product (name,image,price,stock,draft,description,status,created_at,last_update) VALUES ('$name','$storage','$price','$stock','0','$description','$status','','');";

/**
 * @TODO: 
 *  1. Alter table `product_category` and do `product_id` to match the field 
 *     type from table `product`.`product_id`
 *  2. Alter table `product_category` and create its own ID primary key field, 
 *     which can be different from `product_id` 
 */
    $queryInsertProductCategory = "INSERT INTO product_category (product_id, category_id)
    VALUES ('', '$stock');";


 // Run here first query to insert product $queryInsertProduct using mysqli_query()

 // Take ID of the insert product using function mysqli_insert_id()

 // Run second query $queryInsertProductCategory and provide the id from new insert product to the product_id field
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the MySQL `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function to get the auto-increment ID that was assigned in the most recent `INSERT`.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO product (name,image,price,stock,draft,description,status,created_at,last_update) VALUES ('$name','$storage','$price','$stock','0','$description','$status','','');";

$sql .= "INSERT INTO product_category (product_id, category_id)
VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), '$stock');";
```

BTW, the return value of `$con->multi_query()` is just the success of the first query. You need to use `$con->next_result()` to get the success of the second query.

Comment: This worked but i do not understand BTW, the return value of $con->multi_query() is just the success of the first query. You need to use $con->next_result() to get the success of the second query.

Comment: You're executing two `INSERT` queries with `$con->multi_query()`. The value that you're testing with `if()` is just the success of the insert into `product`. If there's an error inserting into `product_category`, that won't be shown there. You have to call `$con->next_result()` to go to get the result of the next query in the sequence.

Comment: Read the documentation of `mysqli_multi_query`, it shows an example of getting all the results in a loop.

Answer (score -1):

You need to get that inserted ID by using function mysqli_insert_id

Comment: He's doing both queries at once using `multi_query()`.

Comment: if also mysqli_insert_id can work you can send the full code to me